# Vue.js - ERROR in Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename index.html

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, assets, conflict

if I create a new vue.js project on my macbook and compile it with "npm run serve", I get the following error. 
I haven't changed any file since creating it.

```
markus@Markuss-MBP meinerstesprojekt % npm run serve

> meinerstesprojekt@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...


 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                    6:12:51 PM

 error  

Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename index.html

ERROR in Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename index.html

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

vue.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
transpileDependencies: true
})

module.exports = {
chainWebpack: (config) => {
config.resolve.symlinks(true)
}
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "meinerstesprojekt",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

npm version: 8.5.3
Node-Version: v16.14.0
Vue-Version: @vue/cli 5.0.1

The following folders are in the path:

```
├── README.md
├── babel.config.js
├── dist
├── jsconfig.json
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
├── src
└── vue.config.js
```

Do you know why this doesn't work? Unfortunately, I couldn't find the solution by searching the web

Comment: I think it might be because of dropbox.

Comment: Alexander Kazakov is right. I had my project under "Dropbox" sync and it gave me the error. Once I had the files moved and free from Dropbox sync, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you hit `vue create your-project-name` Select ([Vue 3] babel,eslint)
and try to `npm run serve`.

And also you can use `vue ui` to start a new project or import old one, and see everything about your project run in a GUI in your browser so you can figure out any problem.

Comment: I´ve tried both options, but the same error occurs

Comment: Can you make a new project with different directory name and in another root folder

Comment: Yes. I chose a another root folder and now it works without problems. Thanks!!

Comment: This does not help those who already had a functioning Vue 2 project and now receive this error.  We need to know what this error means practically and what solutions exist.  

I blame WebPack or whatever tool is emitting this message because it is not specific.  It should have stated the config or libraries that are conflicting.  This error is basically useless.

Answer (score 10):

i was having this issue because of the path to the project was having spaces in the folders name

so i renamed the paths to the project and it works

Example 
from `user/some path here/your-project-name` 
to `user/somePathHere/your-project-name`

and everything starts to work.

Comment: Would like to point that brackets "(" and/or ")" also cause the same issue

Answer (score 5):

Solution:

Step 1: Rename index.html to index.ejs;

Step 2: Add html: { template: './src/index.ejs' } to node_nodules/webpack/bin/webpack.js

The reason for the error may be: When the scaffolding was used to create a project, the names of multiple files were duplicated.

Comment: This answer solved the issue perfectly! I actually followed similar instructions from https://programmerah.com/vue-project-change-directory-run-errormultiple-assets-emit-different-content-to-the-same-filename-index-html-50373/.

Comment: I would note, however, that in case the project is syncing with Dropbox, the issue is solved by simply having the files moved to a new locations and away from Dropbox sync.

Answer (score 2):

I met the issue problem because of "(" and ")" in the path.
Just remove parentheses from path.

Comment: so the solution is...?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My `webpack.config.js` file in the root folder looked like this and I had to comment out the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` declarations:

```
'use strict'
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: [
    './src/app.js'
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: 'vue-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    //   filename: 'index.html',
    //   template: 'index.html',
    //   inject: true
    // })
  ]
}
```

Then it worked.

Answer (score -1):

If you replace `public/index.html` with `public/index2.html` and run it, it will run well.